# asp.net page cant be found

Tags: asp.net

asp.net using the hyperlink

```
<asp:HyperLink ID="HyperLink4" NavigateUrl="~/Diary_Documents/Details.aspx" runat="server" Text="Images"></asp:HyperLink>
```

to bring the user to the details page inside the Diary_Documents folder.

Iv copied the entire Diary_Documents folder to include list, insert, edit and details both aspx and cs.

Pasted it into the customPages folder renamed it 'Diary_Documents2' then changed the hyperlink to

```
<asp:HyperLink ID="HyperLink4" NavigateUrl="~/Diary_Documents2/Details.aspx" runat="server" Text="Images"></asp:HyperLink>
```

but the page cant be found...what am i doing wrong?[image]

Comment: can i see the image of of your folder structure

Comment: If the Diary_Documents2 folder is inside the directory where the page with the hyperlink is there is no need for reference using the "~/" characters from the path. Remove them and try again.

Comment: Thanks for reply guys...tried that no joy...here is my image, even tired renaming 'Diary_Documents' to 'Diary_Documents_OLD', then renamed the 'Diary_Documents2' to 'Diary_Documents' and it worked fine...so why doesnt it work for 2?

Comment: Delete the two folders, saving the important data out of them first, create the one you want, reference it on your hyperlink then try again. Also check any events the hyperlink control has they might be affecting the final result.

Comment: Do not vandalize posts on this site by removing all the useful information from them - including questions you've posted.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looking at the directory structure, unless I'm very much mistaken, the link should either be-

```
<asp:HyperLink NavigateUrl="~/DynamicData/CustomPages/Diary_Documents/Details.aspx" runat="server" Text="Images"></asp:HyperLink>
```

or

```
<asp:HyperLink NavigateUrl="~/DynamicData/CustomPages/Diary_Documents2/Details.aspx" runat="server" Text="Images"></asp:HyperLink>
```

The tilda (~) makes it a relative path from the **root of the application**. Therefore you need to add "DynamicData/CustomPages" to complete the path.

As you don't give the location of the page the link is contained in, I can't show you what the purely HTML relative link would be, but if the page were in "CustomPages" as an example, it would be this-

```
<asp:HyperLink NavigateUrl="Diary_Documents/Details.aspx" runat="server" Text="Images"></asp:HyperLink>
```